# Firebase permissions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have db with this structure:

```
public: {
  UID_1: { ... }, UID_2: { ... }, ...
}
users : {
  UID_1: { ... }, UID_2: { ... }, ...
}
```

And I want set permission to allow read/write to "users" only for proper users (uid owner) and to allow read "public" to everyone, and write for proper users (uid owner).
For now I have

```
    {
    "rules": {
      "users": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
        },
      },
      "public": {
         "$uid": {
           ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
           ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
         }
       }
    }
   }
```

But when I am trying to list all position from "public" by
`this.db.child('public').once('value', snapshot => { ... }`
It doesn't find any value. When I set whole "public" read/write to true it works.
Intuition doesn't work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now nobody has read permission on `/public`, but everyone signed-in user has read permission to each node under it. To be able to read from a location, you need read permission *at that location*.

So to fix the problem, move the `.read` rule in `/public` one level up:

```
  "public": {
     ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
     "$uid": {
       ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
     }
   }
```